# How to select a data set on shiny app?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, reactive

This is my first question as I'm struggling with learning programming...

I'm trying to make a Shiny app that makes a plot according to the data set selected by the user.

Yet I keep getting the following error:-

> ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class character

even though I'm specifying both axis to be numeric.

When I run the `ggplot` code on it's own it makes the plot without issues, so I figure that the problem is on calling to the data set.

I'm calling to base package datasets for this question, but I need an answer that it would do the trick for datasets stored on my pc.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
            sidebarLayout(
              sidebarPanel(selectInput("data", h4("select data"),
                                       choices=c("mtcars" = "mtcars",
                                                 "pressure" = "pressure"))),
            mainPanel(
               PlotOutput("graph")

              )
            ))
```

Server

```
server <- function(input, output) {

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

base <- reactive ({
base <- input$data })

output$graph <- renderPlot({

  ggplot(base(), aes(as.numeric(base[[2]]), as.numeric(base[[3]]))) + 
  geom_col()
})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `input$data` returns a string. It does not return a data.frame that has the same name as the value of that string. And `ggplot()` doesn't work if you pass data.frame as a string:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, cyl)) + geom_point()     #OK
ggplot("mtcars", aes(mpg, cyl)) + geom_point()   # NOT OK
```

Maybe try using

```
base <- reactive ({get(input$data) })
```

which uses `get()` to get an object with the string version of it's name.

But even then `base[[1]]` isn't going to work. When you plot, you should first save the data.frame to a variable. Also, it's not a great idea to repeat data values in the `aes()` -- that's really there to map columns rather than values. Better maybe to use `aes_string()` with the names of the columns. For example

```
output$graph <- renderPlot({
  mydata <- base()    
  ggplot(mydata, aes_string(names(mydata)[2], names(mydata)[3])) + 
  geom_col()
})
```

This works because these are the same

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, disp)) + geom_point()
ggplot(mtcars, aes_string("cyl", "disp")) + geom_point()
ggplot(mtcars, aes_string(names(mtcars)[2], names(mtcars)[3])) + geom_point()
# since
names(mtcars)[2]
# [1] "cyl"
names(mtcars)[3]
# [1] "disp"
```